# Question about Pontryagin duals in Gelfand, Graev, Pyatetskii-Shapiro

Tags: harmonic-analysis, topological-groups, duality-theorems

I am interested in the computation of the Pontryagin duals of certain groups. At the moment I am stuck at a passage of the following book:

> I.M. Gelfand, M.I. Graev, I.I. Pyatetskii-Shapiro, "Representation
> Theory and Automorphic Forms", W.B. Saunders Company, 1969

In the very first paragraph of Chapter 3, the dual of $\mathbb{Z}[p^{-1}]$ is described (the $p$-adic solenoid). I quote the conclusion of the computation:

> Thus the character group of the additive group of all fractions of the form $\frac{a}{p^n}$ has the following structure. We take the additive group whose elements are the pairs $(\alpha,\beta)$, where $\alpha$ is a real number $\bmod 1$ and $\beta$ is a $p$-adic integer. In this group we factor out the subgroup of elements of the form $(r,r)$, where $r$ ranges over all rational numbers whose denominators are not divisible by $p$.

In my own interpretation and notation, the above suggests that the dual of $\mathbb{Z}[p^{-1}]$ is isomorphic to $(\mathbb{R}/ \mathbb{Z}\oplus\mathbb{Z}_p) / \mathbb{Z}_{(p)}$. I have two questions.

1. It is not clear to me where $\mathbb{Z}_{(p)}$ comes from during the computation (assuming it is correct).
2. It is well-known (from other sources) that the dual of $\mathbb{Z}[p^{-1}]$ is isomorphic to $(\mathbb{R}\oplus\mathbb{Z}_p) / \mathbb{Z}$. Are these two computations at odds with each other?

Any comments will be much appreciated.

Comment: $(\Bbb R/\Bbb Z\oplus\Bbb Z_p)/\Bbb Z_{(p)}$ is clearly a proper quotient of $(\Bbb R\oplus\Bbb Z_p)/\Bbb Z$, so it doesn't *seem* like it should be the same group (up to iso). Does whatever "computation" precedes "thus" in the text explain how to interpret the elements as characters?

Comment: I'd ignore the somewhat ad-hoc description given and instead obeserve that $\mathbb Z[p]$ is an inductive limit, and hence its dual is the corresponding projective limit.

Comment: @runway44 Yes, the book exhibits an explicit formula: $$\chi(a/p^n)=\exp 2\pi i(-\alpha + \beta)a/p^n$$.

Comment: @Ruy I already know how to express the dual as a colimit. What I am interested in is in the description given by the book.

Comment: @GabrielChicasReyes What the text is saying doesn't seem to make sense. For example, $(1,0)=(0,0)$ in the supposed character group but the corresponding characters are different. Even if you stipulate the $\alpha$ must be represented by a value in $[0,1)$, the group structure doesn't make sense, e.g. check $(1/2,0)+(1/2,0)=(0,0)$ against the corresponding characters. The most that seems true is the quotient *set* $(\Bbb R/\Bbb Z\oplus\Bbb Z_p)/\Bbb Z_{(p)}$ can be used to parametrize characters, non-homomorphically?